# Get unique array values records with one value exist

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have messenging platform in my app and I'm saving each message in the following format

```
{
   userIds: [ 'user1Id', 'user2Id' ],
   msg: "message",
   sentBy: 'user1',
   sentAt: new Date()
}


{
   userIds: [ 'user1Id', 'user3Id' ],
   msg: "message",
   sentBy: 'user1',
   sentAt: new Date()
}


{
   userIds: [ 'user1Id', 'user2Id' ],
   msg: "message",
   sentBy: 'user1',
   sentAt: new Date()
}
```

Is there any way to get unique  conversations from the collection?

for example from above list I want to get

```
  {
       userIds: [ 'user1Id', 'user2Id' ],
       msg: "message",
       sentBy: 'user1',
       sentAt: new Date()
    }


    {
       userIds: [ 'user1Id', 'user3Id' ],
       msg: "message",
       sentBy: 'user1',
       sentAt: new Date()
    }
```

these two records,

What can be the mongo query here?

Is there any other way  than querying all the records and do unique manually?

or anyone suggests better schema, I just started with this feature so I'm in a position to change schema.

I consider using like

```
{
   userIds: [ 'user1Id', 'user2Id' ],
   msgs: [
    {
       msg: "message",
       sentBy: 'user1',
       sentAt: new Date()
    },
    {
       msg: "message",
       sentBy: 'user2',
       sentAt: new Date()
    }
  ],
   modifiedAt: new Date()
}
```

but decided against it because whenever there is new msg added to msgs array the whole field will be sent to client so using the first schema.

Any suggestions appreaciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use aggregation to do that,

.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$userIds"}}])

Refer [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to more details

And you can use $project option for make the return doc as the format you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you simply use an aggregation. For example:

```
  db.test.aggregate( {$group: {_id: "$userIds" } } )
```

Will return

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : [
                "user1Id",
                "user3Id"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : [
                "user1Id",
                "user2Id"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

You will find more details in the docs [Aggregation-Distinct](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/#Aggregation-Distinct).